# Maven Surefire Plugin Parallel Test Execution - Classes missing from Cobertura Coverage Report

Tags: java, spring-mvc, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-cobertura-plugin

I have a Spring MVC project where I have configured surefire to run tests in parallel using the below options.

```
<forkCount>3</threadCount>
<reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
```

But, after I run the tests with 3 forks, my cobertura coverage report will not contain the data for all the classes. I am suspecting that due to multiple threads, the data is getting over written.

Any workarounds for this?